# Center horizontall images dinamically with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mysqli_fetch_assoc that return me images. I need put all of these images centered horizontally. I try use center-block on all of this, but only center one and the others images goes down.

For example:

If mysql give me 2 images:

```
<body>

<div class="col-xs-12">

<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30" class="center-block">
<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30" class="center-block">

</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ff4rj8zs/

If mysql give me 3 images:

```
<body>

<div class="col-xs-12">

<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30" class="center-block">
<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30" class="center-block">
<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30" class="center-block">

</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/96czjmoh/

As you can see, the images goes down, and don't stay in the same line. I need that all images stay centered in the same line independent of the quantity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<body>

<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30">
<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30">
<img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30">

</div>
</body>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/ff4rj8zs/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3-">
      <img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3-">
      <img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3-">
      <img src="http://osolephp.com.es/grafa/imagenes/imagenesropa/cocinas_6.png?30">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```